# Is there a way to set Title for document in kartik ExportMenu?

Tags: yii2, export, kartik-v

I'm developing a web application to control the information of some energy groups.
I'm using Yii2, with kartik GridView and ExportMenu.
The problem is that I need to set the document title to the exported Excel / Pdf file.

I've searched other posts but can't find anything specific.

Thanks for your help.